# How to force USB device scan programmatically?

Tags: android, usb

I'm writing an Android application working in USB host mode to read data from attached USB storages.

When USB storage first attached to Android device, Android system will mount it automatically(which can be accessed later in **system settings -> Storage & USB**).

Then my app requests an exclusive access to the USB storage using Android USB host APIs. As it is an exclusive access, Android system will broadcast **ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED** event, and no one except my app can access the USB storage.

After my app does what I want to the USB storage, I will release the control to Android system. But Android system will not mount it automatically anymore. I have to plug out and replug in the USB device , to let Android system mount the USB device.

So my question is, is there any method I can trigger Android system to remount the USB storage programmatically?

Comment: Cant you broadcast an action media mounted? Mmmm i think you can but it will not help..

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your idea. I guess normal app does not have permission to send that kind of broadcast. I will have a try.

Comment: Have you found a solution which works on non-rooted devices?

Answer (score 1):

If the device is rooted you can do it like this:

```
    private void replugUsb() {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "replugUsb()");
        try{

            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/authorized\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/authorized\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            su.waitFor();
        }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
            Log.e(APP_TAG, "replugUsb: failed", e);
        }
    }
```